# Is there an ActiveJob equivalent for Resque::Plugins::UniqueJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, rails-activejob

I'm trying to integrate ActiveJob into a Rails 4.2 app, but we're using resque-specific plugins which somewhat of defeat the purpose of being able to swap out queuing backends.

Does ActiveJob provide anything similar to [Resque::Plugins::UniqueJob](https://github.com/engineyard/resque-unique-job)?

Comment: Did you ever find a `UniqueJob` alternative for `ActiveJob`?

Comment: I didn't. Based on my investigation at the time, ActiveJob was missing too much functionality specific to resque/sidekiq, that it'd be better to switch between plug-ins instead of using the ActiveJob abstraction layer.